# Delete row from gridview and also remove item from binding

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, delete-row

I have a GridView filled in using an object this way:

```
   Ingreso I = new Ingreso();
    I.ID_Producto = ID_Producto;
    I.Producto = cmb_producto.Text;
    I.ID_Productor = ID_Productor;
    I.Productor = cmb_productor.Text;
    I.Fecha_Ingreso = Fecha.Value.Date;
    I.Cantidad = Convert.ToInt16(txt_cantidad_ingresada.Text);
    I.Precio_Unitario = Convert.ToDecimal(txt_precio_unitario.Text);
    I.Descripcion = txt_descripcion.Text;

    Ingresos.Add(I);
    ListadeIngresos = new BindingList<Ingreso>(Ingresos);
    BindingSource source = new BindingSource(ListadeIngresos, null);
    Grid_Ingreso.DataSource = source;
```

Then user needs to delete a row that was added, I'm trying this way:

```
 private void Grid_Ingreso_UserDeletingRow(object sender, DataGridViewRowCancelEventArgs e)
        {
            int index = e.Row.Index;
            Ingresos.RemoveAt(index);
            ListadeIngresos.RemoveAt(index);
            BindingSource source = new BindingSource(ListadeIngresos, null);
            Grid_Ingreso.DataSource = source;
        }
```

My problem is that the row gets deleted three times from the gridview and the object (`Ingresos`). It's like the event firing 3 times, but when I debug I only see it entering once. Why this is happening?

Thanks

Comment: You are deleting the row twice in these lines: Ingresos.RemoveAt(index); ListadeIngresos.RemoveAt(index);

Comment: What do you want to do? Why you are trying to delete the item manually while it's going to be deleted by deleting the row?

Comment: Also after creating a `BindingList` from a `List`, it doesn't make sense to remove the item from the `List`. They are two different things without any relation between them.

Comment: When the datagridview is bound, it will propagate the delete to the datasource. Normally you use the UserDeletingRow to check and cancel the delete process (if needed). You can just delete your Grid_Ingreso_UserDeletingRow() Sub from your code.

Comment: Thanks all for your answers, I removed the Grid_Ingreso_UserDeletingRow method and to my surprise the object was updated when I deleted a row, I'm new to gridviews and binding and did not notice the datasource was deleted as well. This can be considered answered